# Extracting strings from an irregularly spaced pdf into a tidy R dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string, pdf

I am struggling to self-teach myself a process for converting an irregularly spaced PDF table into a tidy dataframe in R. My goal is to extract population data from the most recent Pakistani census, which is currently spread out over 137 separate pdfs. [Here](http://www.pbscensus.gov.pk/sites/default/files/bwpsr/kp/ABBOTTABAD_BLOCKWISE.pdf) is an example target file. I have been able to piece together some steps necessary from other guides to break the pdf down into text strings, but have gotten tangled up in regular expressions that I think will be necessary to convert the text further into a dataframe.

Steps I've been able to figure out thus far:

```
# import file
district_import <- pdf_text("http://www.pbscensus.gov.pk/sites/default/files/bwpsr/kp/ABBOTTABAD_BLOCKWISE.pdf")

# convert text to string
data <- toString(district_import)

# convert text to character lines
data <- read_lines(data)

# clean up page headers and footers
header_row_1 <- grep("POPULATION AND HOUSEHOLD DETAIL FROM BLOCK TO DISTRICT LEVEL", data)
header_row_2 <- grep("KHYBER PAKHTUNKHWA", data)
header_row_3 <- grep("ADMIN UNIT", data)
footer_row <- grep("Page ", data)

data <- data[- c(header_row_1, header_row_2, header_row_3, footer_row)]
```

At this stage I can produce the following:

```
> head(data, 15)
 [1] "ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT                                              1,332,912      216,534"
 [2] "     ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL                                             981,590      161,445"
 [3] "           ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT                                   138,311        21183"
 [4] "                        CHARGE NO 01                              138,311         21183"
 [5] "                              CIRCLE NO 01                         12,150          1847"
 [6] "                                     023010101                      5,131           705"
 [7] "                                     023010102                      2,654           435"
 [8] "                                     023010103                      1,004           173"
 [9] "                                     023010104                      2,216           349"
[10] "                                     023010105                         94            14"
[11] "                                     023010106                      1,051           171"
[12] "                              CIRCLE NO 02                         15,383          2435"
[13] "                                     023010201                      1,352           211"
[14] "                                     023010202                      1,019           161"
[15] "                                     023010203                      4,079           691"
```

(Note that although it appears as such through the cut-off point here, the length of leading whitespace is not consistent throughout the document for the various sub-district administrative divisions, and I expect would not be consistent across the 137 districts that I'll ultimately be aiming to loop through and consolidate into a single country-wide dataframe.)

My desired output from this point would be to convert this into a tidy dataframe along the following lines, with the census block (six-digit codes, not identified as such by name in the original pdf) as the basic unit of organization:

```
             district         sub_lvl01             sub_lvl02    sub_lvl03    sub_lvl04 census_block population household
                <chr>             <chr>                 <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      <chr>     <chr>
1 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010101      5,131       705
2 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010102      2,654       435
3 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010103      1,004       173
4 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010104      2,216       349
5 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010105         94        14
6 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01 CIRCLE NO 01    023010106      1,051       171
... etc
```

I have played around with regular expressions in an attempt to figure out how to extract this but am fairly lost in doing so, particularly given the lack of a standard delimiter between variables.

Playing around on regex101.com, I thought this code would at least allow me to extract the population and household figures:

```
 pop_hh_str <- str_match_all(data, "(?!\\d{6})(?<=\\s)\\d*[,.]*\\d*[,.]*\\d*")
```

But this creates a large list, still including blank spaces, and I'm unclear how to transform that into anything resembling a dataframe (or to match up with the other administrative district variables).

Any guidance on how to consider approaching this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DATA**

(since I don't want to install `pdftools`, I recreate your data manually):

```
data <- c("ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT                                              1,332,912      216,534", "     ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL                                             981,590      161,445", "           ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT                                   138,311        21183", "                        CHARGE NO 01                              138,311         21183", "                              CIRCLE NO 01                         12,150          1847", "                                     023010101                      5,131           705", "                                     023010102                      2,654           435", "                                     023010103                      1,004           173", "                                     023010104                      2,216           349", "                                     023010105                         94            14", "                                     023010106                      1,051           171", "                              CIRCLE NO 02                         15,383          2435", "                                     023010201                      1,352           211", "                                     023010202                      1,019           161", "                                     023010203                      4,079           691")
# data is now identical to what you showed as 15 lines of your `data`
```

**PROCESSING: Split strings by whitespaces**

Usually, in such cases, this would do it:

```
strsplit(data, "\\s+") # "\\s+" meaning: 1 or more white spaces
```

But in this case, the characters can have 1 whitespace between the words,
so we want `more than 1 white spaces`, thus `"\\s{2,}"` (at least two ws) as delimiters of the columns.
Secondly, there are leading/trailing whitespaces before and/or after the data, sometimes.
So we pre-clean leading/trailing whitespaces of the line by `trimws()`

Thus:

```
strsplit(trimws(data), "\\s{2,}")
```

We can then rbind those values row by row using `Reduce()`

```
df <- Reduce(rbind, strsplit(trimws(data), "\\s{2,}"))
rownames(df) <- 1:dim(df)[1] # just give at least numbers as rownames
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

output:

```
   [,1]                    [,2]        [,3]     
1  "ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT"   "1,332,912" "216,534"
2  "ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL"     "981,590"   "161,445"
3  "ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT" "138,311"   "21183"  
4  "CHARGE NO 01"          "138,311"   "21183"  
5  "CIRCLE NO 01"          "12,150"    "1847"   
6  "023010101"             "5,131"     "705"    
7  "023010102"             "2,654"     "435"    
8  "023010103"             "1,004"     "173"    
9  "023010104"             "2,216"     "349"    
10 "023010105"             "94"        "14"     
11 "023010106"             "1,051"     "171"    
12 "CIRCLE NO 02"          "15,383"    "2435"   
13 "023010201"             "1,352"     "211"    
14 "023010202"             "1,019"     "161"    
15 "023010203"             "4,079"     "691"
```

From here on, you would need to build helper columns which have counters in which row which type of information appeared ....
Such counts would help you to split the data frame to sub-dataframes. `split()` will be very useful ...

I wrote some functions which might be helpful to classify the 'level' of a row in the `data` vec by counting if it has more than k whitespaces at the start or not.

```
not.more.than.k.leading.whitespaces <- function(s, k) {
  !grepl(paste0("^\\s{", k, ",}"), s)
}

leveler <- function(s, k) {
  cumsum(not.more.than.k.leading.whitespaces(s, k))
}
```

I would use them like this:

```
df$level0 <- leveler(data, 0)
df$level1 <- leveler(data, 5)
df$level2 <- leveler(data, 11)
df$level3 <- leveler(data, 24)
df$level4 <- leveler(data, 37)

# important helper function:
annotate.by.first.row <- function(df, col, col.title) {
  # take first row's column content and add it to the df as a column content
  info <- df[1, col]
  rowsn <- dim(df)[1]
  df.new <- df[2:rowsn, ]
  df.new[, col.title] <- info
  df.new
}

# split data frame to a list of sub data frames
df.l0 <- split(df, df$level0)
# apply our helper function for annotation column generation
# using the information of the first row of the sub data frames
df.a0.l <- lapply(df.l0, annotate.by.first.row, 1, "district")

# cycle through: split, flatten, annotate.by.first.row
# to add next first row information as a column
df.s1.ll <- lapply(df.a0.l, function(df) split(df, df$level1))
df.s1.l <- unlist(df.s1.ll, recursive = FALSE)
df.a1.l <- lapply(df.s1.l, annotate.by.first.row, 1, "thesil")

# repeat the cycles ...
df.s2.ll <- lapply(df.a1.l, function(df) split(df, df$level2))
df.s2.l <- unlist(df.s2.ll, recursive = FALSE)
df.a2.l <- lapply(df.s2.l, annotate.by.first.row, 1, "cantonment")

df.s3.ll <- lapply(df.a2.l, function(df) split(df, df$level3))
df.s3.l <- unlist(df.s3.ll, recursive = FALSE)
df.a3.l <- lapply(df.s3.l, annotate.by.first.row, 1, "charge")

df.s4.ll <- lapply(df.a3.l, function(df) split(df, df$level4))
df.s4.l <- unlist(df.s4.ll, recursive = FALSE)
df.a4.l <- lapply(df.s4.l, annotate.by.first.row, 1, "circle")

# fuse subdata frames by `Reduce(rbind, ...)`
res.df <- Reduce(rbind, df.a4.l)
res.cleaned.df <- res.df[, c("district", "thesil", "cantonment", "charge", "circle", "V1", "V2", "V3")]
```

By such successive steps of splitting, flattening, annotating by first row, you can get to where you want.

```
> res.cleaned.df
#               district            thesil            cantonment       charge
# 6  ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 7  ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 8  ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 9  ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 10 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 11 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 13 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 14 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
# 15 ABBOTTABAD DISTRICT ABBOTTABAD TEHSIL ABBOTTABAD CANTONMENT CHARGE NO 01
#          circle        V1    V2  V3
# 6  CIRCLE NO 01 023010101 5,131 705
# 7  CIRCLE NO 01 023010102 2,654 435
# 8  CIRCLE NO 01 023010103 1,004 173
# 9  CIRCLE NO 01 023010104 2,216 349
# 10 CIRCLE NO 01 023010105    94  14
# 11 CIRCLE NO 01 023010106 1,051 171
# 13 CIRCLE NO 02 023010201 1,352 211
# 14 CIRCLE NO 02 023010202 1,019 161
# 15 CIRCLE NO 02 023010203 4,079 691
```

To do it slightly more compactly and regularly:

```
# abstract over the split-flatten-annotate cycle/pattern by:
spl.fl.annotate <- function(df.a.l, col, col.name) {
  df.sN.ll <- lapply(df.a.l, function(df) split(df, df[, col]))
  df.sN.l  <- unlist(df.sN.ll, recursive = FALSE)
  lapply(df.sN.l, annotate.by.first.row, 1, col.name)
}

# now the cycles can be written as:
df.a0.l <- spl.fl.annotate(list(`0` = df), "level0", "district")
df.a1.l <- spl.fl.annotate(df.a0.l, "level1", "thesil")
df.a2.l <- spl.fl.annotate(df.a1.l, "level2", "cantonment")
df.a3.l <- spl.fl.annotate(df.a2.l, "level3", "charge")
df.a4.l <- spl.fl.annotate(df.a3.l, "level4", "circle")

# fuse subdata frames by `Reduce(rbind, ...)`
res.df <- Reduce(rbind, df.a4.l)
res.cleaned.df <- res.df[, c("district", "thesil", "cantonment", "charge", "circle", "V1", "V2", "V3")]
```

Comment: Thank you! Will need to figure out a function to group the census blocks by their associated administrative sub-divisions but I think I should be able to follow this.

Comment: Yes, do you know the function `split()`? You need a helper column which indicates to which group your data should belong ...

Comment: Now I accomplished it! :) It might be that the values for the `leveler()` function have to be modified - I had only empty spaces preceding the data line ... but this was what I was telling about to use the preceding white spaces as information which level the information of the row reflects. My example codes should all run through... I hope that helped!

Comment: That's amazing. My attempt at a solution was going to be much clunkier. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @cjsc: Welcome! It took me quite some while - though I had some intuitive feeling that this approach leads to something... Happy if it helped you! ;)  Now I abstracted over the repetitive pattern again using a function ... I think this example shows the power of functional programming (FP). `lapply()` is a typical higher order function... And it is typical for FP, that you use small helper functions which then together with other function prove to be very powerful in guiding the processes. R is a FP language. It shines when using FP approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I can get you on the way with a bit of code for getting the census_block out into a data.frame. If you can get a lookup table for the census blocks you can add the rest of the data.

Continuing from your data vector:

```
library(stringr)

# find the rows which have 9 digits + a space
data1 <- data[which(str_detect(data, "\\d{9} "))]
# remove spaces in front of the line
data1 <- str_remove(data1, " +")
# replace all other spaces with 1 space
data1 <- str_replace_all(data1, " +", " ")

# create data.frame and split the value column into 3 with new headers.
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data1  %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  separate(value ,into = c("census_block", "population", "household"), sep = " ")
df  
# A tibble: 1,106 x 3
   census_block population household
   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>    
 1 023010101    5,131      705      
 2 023010102    2,654      435      
 3 023010103    1,004      173      
 4 023010104    2,216      349      
 5 023010105    94         14       
 6 023010106    1,051      171      
 7 023010201    1,352      211      
 8 023010202    1,019      161      
 9 023010203    4,079      691      
10 023010204    2,171      345      
# ... with 1,096 more rows
```